# On MongoDB , command mongostat not work , error username

Tags: mongodb

i have a problem with  mongostat .

test1 :

```
mongostat
2019-11-15T16:06:55.722+0100 Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers
```

test2:

```
mongostat -u "dominio\\username" -p password--host hostname --authenticationMechanism PLAIN --authenticationDatabase '$external' --ssl --sslCAFile /pathcert
2019-11-15T16:07:44.682+0100 Failed: not authorized on admin to execute command { serverStatus: 1, recordStats: 0, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "admin" }.
```

I have 2 questions:
- with mongostat can i specify a specific DB?
- the username that privileges need to have?

How can I resolve these?

Comment: Only db user admin can execute this command ?